# Is "dante" a participle in Ps 103:28

Tags: verbs, grammar-identification, vulgata

What parts of the verb are *dante* and *aperiente* in Ps 103:28 (Vulgate)?

*dante te illis colligent aperiente te manum tuam omnia implebuntur bonitate.*

My guess is the ablative of the present participle (Kennedy, Section 74 note 1)?

Comment: Your guess is correct, they are both present participles forming parts of ablative absolutes.

Comment: Many thanks! Inching forwards in knowledge.